# Is there any way in python to detect the amplitude of a wave at some point of time in a .wav or any audio file?

Tags: python, audio, soundwaves

I've been using a bit of numpy and pysinewave to generate and analyse some sine waves and turn them into audio, but now that I have the audio I couldn't think of a way to detect the frequency or amplitude of the waves at some point of time, for example, I want to detect the amplitude of a wave in the audio in second one. Is there a way to do this in python with some library?

I tried trying to convert the audio files back into numpy to get the waves and try to sort of detect the amplitude every x seconds but I think my problem is way more simple to solve and I am overthinking it

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325804/how-do-i-find-amplitude-of-wav-file-in-python